# Interface object instantiation and n-layer encapsulation

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, factories

We are bulding a system that we want the final implementation do "hide" the data access layer (so that we can change it in the future).

So the idea is that the application code will call an interface that will be implemented by Database access objects. So we have the interface class:

```
public interface DatabaseInterface

    {
        void Create(DataObject obj);
    }
```

Then we have the class that implements the interface:

```
public class DatabaseAccess : DatabaseInterface

    { 
        void Create(DataObject obj)
        { 
            Entity dbContext = new Entity();

            dbContext.Data.Add (obj);
            dbContext.SaveChanged();
       }
    }
```

Together will all this, we have the DataObject class:

```
public class DataObject
{
     integer Data1;
     string  Data2;
}
```

OUr problems sits on the main application, as I don´t know what is the DatabaseInterface implementation:

```
public class CreateElementOnDatabase

    {
         DataObject myObj = new DataObject();
         myObj.Data1 = 10;
         myObj.Data2 = "Test String";

         var dbAccess = new DatabaseInterface() <=== I know this is not possible, but don´t know what to do!!!!

         dbAccess.Create (myObj);
    }
```

How do I call the implemented method without knowing which class did it ? Surely I´m missing something on my design.

We *REALLY* wanna make the application fully independent from the code below.

[EDIT 1]

These implementations reside in different class libraries. So I have the following:
App project
DatabaseInterface project
DatabaseAccess project
DataObject project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are missing is a "factory" class that builds instances for outside world based on parameters or configuration settings it receives (if they want to have the outside world influencing its behavior) or make their own decisions, i.e. they will create the instances of either type A or B based on their internal logic that cannot be changed from the outside.
In the code below you will see the DatabaseFactory which is what you were missing. Also, note the private/public/internal modifiers which are important to make sure you expose what is needed and not more than you need (making all classes public creates confusions to those who want to use your library)

Here is the code

```
// interfaces must be public - this is the "contract" with the outside world / assemblies
public interface IDatabase
{
    void Create(DataObject obj);
}

// classes that implement interfaces should be internal - outside world don't know about them
internal class SQLDatabase : IDatabase
{
    // internal on constructor helps you to make sure you are the only one 
    // that can create such an instance
    internal SQLDatabase()
    {
    }
    void Create(DataObject obj)
    {
        Entity dbContext = new Entity();
        dbContext.Data.Add(obj);
        dbContext.SaveChanged();
    }
}
internal class OracleDatabase : IDatabase
{
    internal OracleDatabase()
    {
    }
    void Create(DataObject obj)
    {
        //oracle creation method
    }
}

public class DataObject
{
    int Data1;
    string Data2;
}

// this is the factory class that creates the instances for you (ourside world)
public class DatabaseFactory
{
    // you can use either params or ideally app.config keys
    public IDatabase CreateInstace()
    {
        if (ConfigSetting == "SQL")
        {
            return new SQLDatabase();
        }
        else if (ConfigSetting == "Oracle")
        {
            return new OracleDatabase();
        }
        else throw new System.Exception ("invalid configuration setting key");
    }
}

// this is in external assembly:
public class CreateElementOnDatabase
{
     DataObject myObj = new DataObject();
     myObj.Data1 = 10;
     myObj.Data2 = "Test String";

    // you only work with public interfaces
    // and the factory creates the instances for you ...
     IDatabase db = DatabaseFactory.CreateInstace();
     db.Create(myObj);
}
```

Comment: Great post. This is what a wanna do... BUT... All classes are on independent ClassLibraries and I´m messy building that factory. So, imagening that I have 4 libs (App, DatabaseInterface, DatabaseAccess and DataObject), where should I put the factory and how are the project references gonna behave. (See last topic comments. I will be editing the original post)

Comment: What you can do is: Lib A - IDatabase, IDBObject, and the DatabaseFactory. Lib B_SQL - Implements SQLDatabase - it will reference the LibA and would expose a static class DatabaseCreator with a method CreateInstance, Lib B_Oracle - will do the same as Lib B_SQL. I hope that Lib A will be able to dynamically load either B_Oracle or B_SQL, and call the DatabaseCreator.CreateInstance method. Not sure if this is what you were looking for... is it?

Comment: oh - and IDatabase should be referenced by all upper libraries

Comment: No. I don´t want to create different db instances. What I want is to keep App using only the interface class and lib and make the interface decide what kind of implementation it has available (depending on a app parameter). I don´t want to referente any database stuff from the App. I can make it all work, but when I put the factory in Interface, I have to reference the Database lib and this gives me cycling reference, as I need the database lib to reference the interface in order to implement it. Seens a black hole after some hours trying to accomplish that.

Comment: Just to clarify, my goal is to make App make no reference to any database related class at all, only the database interface class. But if I have a factory, this needs to reference the database implementation and that breaks my legs, as I cannot put that at the interface class.

Comment: Mendez, i said IDatabase meaning the library that contains the interfaces. Your factory stays together with the interfaces. Database implementations are not referenced by your app. You said: I have 4 projects: The App, the DatabaseAccess, the DatabaseInterface and the DataObject. App references the DatabaseInterface (where the factory is). The DatabaseAccess (I assume) is the one to actually hold the database implementation. This library will also reference the DatabaseInterface. And finally, the DataObject i assume you can keep it outside all libraries...

Comment: re: to your last comment, "If i have a factory, this needs to reference the database implementation" - no, if you dynamically load your assembly you don't need to do this. you can use the interfaces commonly known by multiple layers.

Comment: Yes. That´s what I wanna do. But if I put the Factory inside the interface, I need to add a reference to the DatabaseAccess (the lib that really access the database). As this lib is referencing the interface (actually this lib implements the interface), I´m getting circular reference... Sound I´m missing something obvious... The dynamic load assembly ??? Yes, the model is free of references and is used by all libs.

Comment: right, Factory will do an Activator.CreateInstance("YourClassType") and i think you can cast the result to your IDatabase (interface) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx

Comment: I think @Daniel is right ... It really depends on what you mean when you say "fully independent from the source code" :)

Comment: Great. I got the point. I don´t know exactly how to do it, but I will take a look. I will vote up as this was very helpfull. Thanks Jerez.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that would create the correct DAL object.
Something like this:

```
public class RepositoryFactory {
    public static DatabaseInterface MakeDAL() {
        return new DatabaseAccess();
    }
}
```

Then, to make a DAL object:

```
var dbAccess = RepositoryFactory.MakeDAL();
```

Depending on how much separation you want between the app and the database access, you would put the interfaces, the interface implementations, and the factory class in separate assemblies, or put some in one assembly and some in another. It really depends on what you mean when you say "fully independent from the source code".

Comment: I forgot to tell that these implementations are in different libs. Where should I put this class - in the same lib as the DatabaseInterface or in the DatabaseAccess lib ?

Comment: So you have 3 projects: your app, the interfaces, and the Database Access? And your app references the Database Access and the interfaces? And the Database Access references the interfaces?

Comment: I have 4 projects: The App, the DatabaseAccess, the DatabaseInterface and the DataObject. I have tried already to build a factory, but if I put the factory on DatabaseAccess, I need to reference it from the App and that breaks the architecture. I tried to build a factory interface, but I cannot add a reference to DatabaseAccess from DatabaseInterface, as it´s being referenced the other way....